# PayPal Authorization for API with Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, paypal-rest-sdk

The following fails with the error :{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}. It is unclear what aspect of the syntax needs to change as I have used the same format for another API and it has worked. The only difference I can see is PayPal's link has OAuth2 as the access tokens type, however they do define that Basic can be used with their suggested development platform Postman.

https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/

```
function GetPayPalToken(){
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(PayPalClientID+':'+PayPalKey)
    },
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    muteHttpExceptions: true
});
console.log(response.getContentText());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the documentation referenced, the body must be `grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: Could you elaborate? It appears the particular syntax is incorrect as I have it. Could you provide the corrected code from what I shared?